# Avoid overriding when two IF statements contain the same int?

Tags: java

I'm working on an assignment in Java programming about calculating your age in days, without any Date classes. Here is the part of the code where I'm stuck. As you can see the second IF uses the same int as the first IF if both are true.

```
int åSkillnad = år - years; 
int mSkillnad = (månad + 1) - months; 
int dSkillnad = dag - days; 

if (mSkillnad < 0) { 
    åSkillnad = åSkillnad - 1; 
    mSkillnad = 12 + mSkillnad; 
    System.out.println(mSkillnad); 
} 

if (dSkillnad < 0) { 
    mSkillnad = mSkillnad - 1; 
    dSkillnad = månader[months - 1] + dSkillnad; 
    System.out.println(mSkillnad); 
    System.out.println(dSkillnad); 
}
```

The problem that I can't solve is that if both the Month and Day difference are negative when subtracting the current date and the date you were born on, the second IF statement gets the new value of mSkillnad which was used in the first IF statement. Is there any way to work around this?

Comment: I'm failing to see why it actually matters that `mSkillnad` is updated by the first `if` statement before the second one executes.

Comment: Please post your solution for the benefit of others.

Comment: @user3365436 glad you solved it. If you want to close off this question, you can either post an answer with your solution, or just delete the question.

Comment: I presume you just needed "else if" in the second case...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine your task as simple subtraction operation. Like in primary school :D

If you have numbers, for example, 532 and 189, and you need to calculate 532-189=?

You start to subtracting from the last digit, right? As in:

```
 532          532         532
-189         -189        -189
----         ----        ----
   3           43         343
```

So, it is the same here, if you want to calculate the difference between two dates, you should subtract and calculate the smallest part first - the day count. Then (after you adjusted month count depending on the day count) calculate month count and only then the year count.

Simply: Swap places of your both IF blocks so that it goes like this:

```
int åSkillnad = år - years; 
int mSkillnad = (månad + 1) - months; 
int dSkillnad = dag - days; 

if (dSkillnad < 0) { 
    ...
}

if (mSkillnad < 0) { 
    ...
}
```